# wp_enqueue_style not working if the file is in a sub folder

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I use wp astra to customize our site and have set up a child theme but for some reason, the wp_enqueue_style is not working if the file is in a subfolder.

When I view source the page, it does output the URL like this `<link rel='stylesheet' id='my-css-css'  href='https://my-domain-url/wp-content/themes/astra-child/assets/css/style.css?ver=1.1' media='all' />` but when I click and visit the URL I get 404 page not found.

Here's the wp enqueue code.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), '1.1', 'all' );
```

This one works if I put the file inside the main folder of the child theme.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), '1.1', 'all' );
```

Can anyone help and explain why it doesn't work?

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Are you sure the file `astra-child/assets/css/style.css` exists? Have you tried clearing your caches, e.g. reload the page?

Comment: Hi Sally CJ, yes I did, I even  tried it on other browser, safari, chrome and firefox all have the same results. Thanks!

Comment: If you put it in the root and it works, and then move it to `assets` and adjust the path... ...and it doesn't work...  that is definitely odd behaviour.  It looks like it should be working.  Can you double check everything for a typo or extra whitespace somewhere.  It really looks as though it should work.

Comment: Hello Tony! I double checked everything, the folder path, I even tried to create a new CSS folder outside the assets folder, store the file in there, still, it didn't work. But when I tried to enqueue scripts in the same folder assets it worked, and then also move the js file to assets/js/ then it worked as well. The weird part is why I'm not able to enqueue any css file into a sub folder. Thanks!

Comment: Hello guys, all working now.  :) The problem is with my FTP client transmit, been navigating through the child theme folder using transmit, and created the file directly.  When I go to file manager, I saw the folder is empty, but on transmit I can see the files are in there, so I uploaded the CSS file using file manager, then viola! Issue resolved. Though, not sure why my FTP client keeps seeing the file when in fact the folder is empty. Anyways, thank you for all your help!

Comment: I don't have issues of FTP client. but I m still suffering from it.  did find any solutions. may be this problem happens in latest wordpress version . and probably  the reason there are not enough discussions  on this issue. is there any geek guy to solve this problem?